# PHP Send Form Data & Two Different Emails

Tags: php, forms, email, post

- PHP version: 5.3.3
- PHPMailer version: 6.0.5
- CentOS release: 6.9

I am using the script below to send form data to a specific email address. It works as expected.

```
    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
        $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
        $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($phone)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        $recipient = "email@domain.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $emailsubject = "New contact from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Phone:\n$phone\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $emailsubject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo 'Thank You! Your message has been sent.';
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }
```

I would now like to send a separate email to the **sender's email** (`$email`), with a different email body - something like;

> Thank you for your submission. These are the details you submitted...

Any advice is appreciated.

*note: I know my PHP version is insecure*

Comment: you can easily use a simple `if` statement. `if($email == 'the_email'){`

Comment: Also note `$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);` . `$email` is a boolean value

Comment: for 2 different body, 2 different mail you must have 2 separated body "linked" to each mail address and iterate in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple if statement for this. What you do is to send the mail to the custom sender address after the initial mail has been successfully sent.

```
<?php

//verify that email is valid
if ($email === true) {
    if (mail($recipient, $emailsubject, $email_content, $email_headers) === true) {
        //start processing mail for custom sender email
        //custom content
        $customContent = '';
        $customContent .= 'Thank you for your submission. These are the details you submitted..';
        if (mail($_POST['email'], 'Custom-Subject', $customContent, $email_headers) === true) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo 'Thank You! Your message has been sent.';
        }
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }
} else {
   echo 'Your email address is invalid';
   die;
}
```

Also note `$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);` . `$email` is a boolean value(true/false). `$_POST['email'];` contains the actual email address